# Updating JPanel text in another class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, settext

I try to update some label texts from a class in another one, but I don't succeed. This is only a part of the entire code, but the entire code is about 500 lines... I can post it on request.

```
public class Allo  implements ActionListener {


JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();
static JButton[][] bouton; 
static int board[][] = new int[16][8]; 

int compteMiss =  0; 
int essais = 0;
int coupsReussis = 0;

int navire1 = 0;
int navire2 = 0;
int naviresCoules = 0;

int destroyer1 = 0;
int destroyer2 = 0;
int destroyer3 = 0;
int destroyersCoules = 0;

int sousMarin1 = 0;
int sousMarin2 = 0;
int sousMarin3 = 0;
int sousMarin4 = 0;
int sousMarinsCoules = 0;

static String nom;
int admin = 0;
String choixclique = "D2";


public Allo(int width, int height) {
SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
fenetre.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

bouton = new JButton[16][8];


for (int r = 0; r < 16; r++)
{
for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
{    
bouton[r][c] = new JButton(" ");   
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, bouton[r][c], r*30+100, SpringLayout.NORTH, fenetre.getContentPane());
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, bouton[r][c], c*40+300, SpringLayout.WEST, fenetre.getContentPane());
bouton[r][c].setSize(40,40);
bouton[r][c].addActionListener(new ButtonPressed(r,c));

fenetre.getContentPane().add(bouton[r][c]);
}
}

fenetre.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(173, 216, 230));
fenetre.setSize(900, 700);
fenetre.setResizable(false);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

fenetre.getContentPane().add(panel);
SpringLayout sl_panel = new SpringLayout();
panel.setLayout(sl_panel);

JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel_1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel_1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, fenetre.getContentPane());
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel_1, 662, SpringLayout.NORTH, fenetre.getContentPane());
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1, 202, SpringLayout.WEST, fenetre.getContentPane());
fenetre.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
SpringLayout sl_panel_1 = new SpringLayout();
panel_1.setLayout(sl_panel_1);

JLabel lblRsultats = new JLabel("R\u00E9sultats");
lblRsultats.setForeground(new Color(148, 0, 211));
lblRsultats.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblRsultats, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel_1);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblRsultats, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(lblRsultats);


JLabel lblSurDestroyers = new JLabel("Sur 3 Destroyers:");
lblSurDestroyers.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblSurDestroyers, 40, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblRsultats);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblSurDestroyers, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(lblSurDestroyers);

JLabel labelDestroyers = new JLabel("0");
labelDestroyers.setForeground(new Color(147, 112, 219));
labelDestroyers.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelDestroyers, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblSurDestroyers);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, labelDestroyers, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(labelDestroyers);


JLabel lblSurNavires = new JLabel("Sur 2 Navires:");
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblSurNavires, 16, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblSurDestroyers);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblSurNavires, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, lblRsultats);
lblSurNavires.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
panel_1.add(lblSurNavires);

JLabel labelNavires = new JLabel("0");
labelNavires.setForeground(new Color(147, 112, 219));
labelNavires.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelNavires, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblSurNavires);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, labelNavires, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(labelNavires);


JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Sur 4 Sous-Marins:");
lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNewLabel, 13, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblSurNavires);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblNewLabel, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

JLabel labelSousMarins = new JLabel("0");
labelSousMarins.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
labelSousMarins.setForeground(new Color(147, 112, 219));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelSousMarins, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblNewLabel);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, labelSousMarins, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(labelSousMarins);


JLabel lblNombreDeCoups = new JLabel("Nombre de coups rat\u00E9s:");
lblNombreDeCoups.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
lblNombreDeCoups.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNombreDeCoups, 18, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblNewLabel);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblNombreDeCoups, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel_1);
panel_1.add(lblNombreDeCoups);

JLabel labelCoupsRates = new JLabel("0");
labelCoupsRates.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
labelCoupsRates.setForeground(Color.RED);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelCoupsRates, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblNombreDeCoups);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, labelCoupsRates, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, labelDestroyers);
panel_1.add(labelCoupsRates);


JLabel lblNombreDeCoups_1 = new JLabel("Nombre de coups r\u00E9ussis:");
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNombreDeCoups_1, 23, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblNombreDeCoups);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblNombreDeCoups_1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblRsultats);
lblNombreDeCoups_1.setForeground(Color.RED);
lblNombreDeCoups_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
panel_1.add(lblNombreDeCoups_1);

JLabel labelCoupsReussis = new JLabel("0");
labelCoupsReussis.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
labelCoupsReussis.setForeground(Color.RED);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelCoupsReussis, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNombreDeCoups_1);
sl_panel_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, labelCoupsReussis, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, labelDestroyers);
panel_1.add(labelCoupsReussis);



JLabel lblJeuBatailleNavale = new JLabel("Jeu Bataille Navale 1614");
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblJeuBatailleNavale, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, fenetre.getContentPane());
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblJeuBatailleNavale, 157, SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1);
springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblJeuBatailleNavale, 374, SpringLayout.EAST, panel_1);
lblJeuBatailleNavale.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
fenetre.getContentPane().add(lblJeuBatailleNavale);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
labelDestroyers.setText(ButtonPressed.getText());
}
fenetre.setVisible(true);

}


public class ButtonPressed implements ActionListener 
{   
public void setText() {
int coupsReussis = 1;
}

public String getText() {
return coupsReussis;
}

int x; //rang
int y ;//colonne

public ButtonPressed(int rang, int colonne)
{
x = rang;
y = colonne;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if (board[x][y] == 3) {

bouton[x][y].setText("N3");

for (int r = 0; r < 16; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
    {    
        if ((bouton[x][y].getName() == "a") && (bouton[x][y].getText() == "N3") && (navire1 != 3)) {
            navire1 = navire1 + 1;
            bouton[x][y].setName("A");
            if (navire1 == 3) {
                naviresCoules = naviresCoules + 1;
            }

        } else {
            if ((bouton[x][y].getName() == "b") && (bouton[x][y].getText() == "N3") && (navire2 != 3)) {
                navire2 = navire2 + 1;
                bouton[x][y].setName("B");
                if (navire2 == 3) {
                    naviresCoules = naviresCoules + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

essais++;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the `String` variable is from another `Class` you could try a basic Get/Set method like this:

```
public void setText() {
   String aVariable = "some text";
}

public String getText() {
   return aVariable;
}
```

Then set it in the class you're trying to call it from by doing this

```
ClassName class = new ClassName();
```

and inside your method do this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    labelDestroyers.setText(class.getText());
}
```

**Edit** use this code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ButtonPressed bp = new ButtonPressed();
    labelDestroyers.setText(bp.getText());
    }
```

An alternative from what I see is you could just declare a string and use that like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String st = "the text you want";
        labelDestroyers.setText(st);
}
```

You need to initialize the class before it can be used. Also you use the name that you give the class, not the actual name of the class

Comment: @NicolasLamoureux post the code for the `Class` you are trying to call the `variable` from in you're original post

Comment: What line are you trying to update with `setText` that isn't working?

Comment: I want to update this JLabel:
JLabel labelDestroyers = new JLabel("0");

while using this class:
public class ButtonPressed implements ActionListener

In the method: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

Comment: @NicolasLamoureux see edit, that should work. Even though I don't see why you need to declare this in your other class. From what I can see it's not being changed by actually pressing the button. I do not see the variable `coupsReussis` anywhere else. Anyways, it will work, cheers!

Comment: Also if you need to use that class's variables throughout your `Allo Class` you will want to add the line `ButtonPressed bp = new ButtonPressed();` at the top of your `Allo Class` just after `JFrame fenetre = new JFrame();`

Comment: I don't get it; if possible, i would like to update labelDestroyers while i'm in the ButtonPressed class, and something like labelDestroyers.setText(labelDestroyers.getText+1);

And sorry, I keep hitting the enter key in case of shift-enter...
If it is not possible, I could use a "int nbDestroyers = 0;", and do something like  If ... nbDestroyers = nbDestroyers +1; labelDestroyers.setText(nbDestroyers);